# Log gmail threads in a text file

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gmail

I'm trying to retrieve back 30 days emails from Gmail and logging them in a text file. The catch is every thread should be logged into their text file respectively. So the script should produce same number of text files as compared to number of threads are there in gmail for last 30 days.

I'm writing this in pure ruby using `gmail` gem. Below I tried to get X-Gm-THRID but `nil` is the output

```
gmail = Gmail.new(username, password)
gmail.inbox.emails(:after => Date.today - 30).each do |email|
   response = gmail.conn.fetch(email.uid, '(X-GM-THRID)')
   puts response.inspect
end
```

Reference link:
https://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail/issues/43

Answer (score 1):

Okay I've figured out myself

```
gmail.conn.uid_fetch(uid, "X-GM-THRID")
```

I used this command to retrieve thread ID of the conversation.